# How to use python to parse XML to required custom fields

Tags: python, xml, glob, elementtree, force.com

I've got a directory full of salesforce objects in XML format.  I'd like to identify the `<fullName>` and parent file of all the custom `<fields>` where `<required>` is true.  Here is some truncated sample data, lets call it "Custom_Object__c:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomObject xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<deprecated>false</deprecated>
<description>descriptiontext</description>
<fields>
    <fullName>custom_field1</fullName>
    <required>false</required>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>custom_field2</fullName>
    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
    <visibleLines>5</visibleLines>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>custom_field3</fullName>
    <required>false</required>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>custom_field4</fullName>
    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
    <description>custom field 4 description</description>
    <externalId>true</externalId>
    <required>true</required>
    <scale>0</scale>
    <type>Number</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</fields>
<fields>
    <fullName>custom_field5</fullName>
    <deprecated>false</deprecated>
    <description>Creator of this log message. Application-specific.</description>
    <externalId>true</externalId>
    <label>Origin</label>
    <length>255</length>
    <required>true</required>
    <type>Text</type>
    <unique>false</unique>
</fields>
<label>App Log</label>
<nameField>
    <displayFormat>LOG-{YYYYMMDD}-{00000000}</displayFormat>
    <label>Entry ID</label>
    <type>AutoNumber</type>
</nameField>
</CustomObject>
```

The desired output would be a dictionary with format something like:

```
required_fields =  {'Custom_Object__1': 'custom_field4', 'Custom_Object__1': 'custom_field5',... etc for all the required fields in all files in the fold.}
```

or anything similar.

I've already gotten my list of objects through glob.glob, and I can get a list of all the children and their attributes with ElementTree but I'm struggling past there.  I feel like I'm very close but I'd love a hand finishing this task off.  Here is my code so far:

```
import os
import glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

os.chdir("/Users/paulsallen/workspace/fforce/FForce Dev Account/config/objects/")
objs = []


for file in glob.glob("*.object"):
    objs.append(file)

fields_dict = {}

for object in objs:
    root = ET.parse(objs).getroot()

....
```

and once I get the XML data parsed I don't know where to take it from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You really want to switch to using [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) here, because then you can use an XPath query:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

os.chdir("/Users/paulsallen/workspace/fforce/FForce Dev Account/config/objects/")
objs = glob.glob("*.object")

fields_dict = {}

for filename in objs:
    root = ET.parse(filename).getroot()
    required = root.xpath('.//n:fullName[../n:required/text()="true"]/text()',
        namespaces={'n': tree.nsmap[None]})
    fields_dict[os.path.splitext(filename)[0]] = required
```

With that code you end up with a dictionary of lists; each key is a filename (without the extension), each value is a list of required fields.

The XPath query looks for `fullName` elements in the default namespace, that have a `required` element as sibling with the text `'true'` in them. It then takes the contained text of each of those matching elements, which is a list we can store in the dictionary.

Comment: you can also use this XPath expression: `root.xpath("//*[local-name()='fullName' and ./following-sibling::*[local-name()='required' and text()='true']]")` (given for completeness only). Great answer, though +1

Comment: @isedev: Yeah, the `local-name()` alternative is so much more verbose that I just didn't bother with it.

Comment: @isedev: Also, I presumed that the `required` tag could also *precede* the `fullName` tag, so I avoided `following-sibling`.

Comment: great solution but it is worth noting that you must declare tree =ET.parse(filename) or the namespaces argument doesn't work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad it works for you; I tested this with `ET.XML()` instead of parsing an on-disk file so I could have missed that detail.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function to find all required fields under a given root. It should also help as an example/starting point for future parsing needs

```
def find_required_fields(root):
    NS = {'soap': 'http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata'}
    required_fields = []
    for field in root.findall('soap:fields', namespaces=NS):
        required = field.findtext('soap:required', namespaces=NS) == "true"
        name = field.findtext('soap:fullName', namespaces=NS)
        if required:
            required_fields.append(name)
    return required_fields
```

Example usage:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.parse('objects.xml') # where objects.xml contains the example in the question
>>> print find_required_fields(root)
['custom_field4', 'custom_field5']
>>>
```